# First text based Java program

Tags: java

I am learning Java and this is my first big project. I am designing a text based Chess game using Java. I have managed to get the castling work but for some reason I couldn't get the Pawns to move. I would love to share the rest of the code but i can't because of the character limit however I would love to send the whole program to u via DM.

```
package il.co.Pawn;
import il.co.ChessInterface.ChessPiece;
public class Pawn extends ChessPiece{
    int columnEnd;
    int rowEnd;
    int columnStart;
    int rowStart;
    String name;
    boolean simpleMove;
    boolean twoSquareMove;
    boolean devourMove;
    boolean valid;
    String chessPiece;
    boolean pieceDevour;
    char firstLetter;
    char secondLetter;
    boolean secondLetterNotNull;
    public Pawn(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pawn [name=" + name + "]";
    }
    //pieces, columnStart,rowStart,columnEnd,rowEnd
    public boolean isMoveValid(ChessPiece[][] pieces, int columnStart,  int rowStart, int columnEnd, int rowEnd) {
        int deltaX = rowEnd - rowStart;
        if (deltaX == 1 || deltaX == -1)
            simpleMove = true;
        boolean pieceMove1 = false;
        boolean pieceMove2 = false;
        boolean pieceMove3 = false;
        boolean pieceMove4 = false;
        pieceMove1 = true;
        pieceMove2 = true;
        pieceMove3 = true;
        pieceMove4 = true;
        return pieceMove1  || pieceMove2 || pieceMove3 || pieceMove4;

    }
    //This part displays the Pawns at their respective locations and it is used to differentiate between the White pieces and black pieces.
    String pawn="";
    public String print() {
        if(name.charAt(0)=='B'){
            pawn= "|"+ name + "|";
        }
        else{
            pawn="|"+ name + "|";
        }
        return pawn;
    }
    @Override
    //This part finds the piece in the board.
    public String FindPiece() {
        return this.name;
    }

    //pieces,rowStart,columnStart ,columnEnd,rowEnd
    //this method is the part where the program checks if the piece is moving in accordance to the rules or not.
    public boolean piecesCollision(ChessPiece[][]pieces,int rowStart,int columnStart ,int columnEnd,int rowEnd) {
        boolean isPawnMovingUP=false;
        boolean isPawnMovingUP2=false;
        boolean isPawnMovingRIGHT=false;
        boolean isPawnMovingDOWN=false;
        boolean isPawnMovingDOWN2=false;
        boolean isPawnMovingLEFT=false;
        if(pieces[rowStart][columnStart].FindPiece().charAt(0)=='W'){
            if(rowStart==7 && (rowEnd==6 ||  rowEnd==5) && columnStart==columnEnd){
                isPawnMovingUP = true;
            }
            else if((rowStart-1)==rowEnd && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]==null && columnStart==columnEnd){
                isPawnMovingUP2 = true;
                //isPawnMovingUP = true;
            }
            else{
                //isPawnMovingUP = false;
                isPawnMovingUP2 = false;
            }
        }
        if(pieces[rowStart][columnStart].FindPiece().charAt(0)=='B'){
            if(rowStart==2 && (rowEnd==3 ||  rowEnd==4)&& columnStart==columnEnd){
                isPawnMovingDOWN = true;
            }
            else if((rowStart+1)==rowEnd && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]==null && columnStart==columnEnd){
                //isPawnMovingDOWN2 = true;
                //============================
                isPawnMovingDOWN = true;
                //============================
            }
            else{
                isPawnMovingDOWN = false;
                //isPawnMovingDOWN2 = false;
            }
        }
        if(pieces[rowStart][columnStart].FindPiece().charAt(0)=='W'){
            if(isPawnMovingDOWN == false && (rowStart-1)==rowEnd && (columnStart-1)==columnEnd  && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]!=null && piecesDevour(pieces, rowStart, columnStart , columnEnd, rowEnd)==true && columnStart!=columnEnd){
                //if(isPawnMovingDOWN2 == false && isPawnMovingDOWN == false && (rowStart-1)==rowEnd && (columnStart-1)==columnEnd  && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]!=null && piecesDevour(pieces, rowStart, columnStart , columnEnd, rowEnd)==true && columnStart!=columnEnd){
                isPawnMovingLEFT=true;

            }
            else if(isPawnMovingDOWN == false &&(rowStart-1)==rowEnd && (columnStart+1)==columnEnd  && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]!=null && piecesDevour(pieces, rowStart, columnStart , columnEnd, rowEnd)==true&& columnStart!=columnEnd){
                //else if(isPawnMovingDOWN2 == false && isPawnMovingDOWN == false &&(rowStart-1)==rowEnd && (columnStart+1)==columnEnd  && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]!=null && piecesDevour(pieces, rowStart, columnStart , columnEnd, rowEnd)==true&& columnStart!=columnEnd){
                isPawnMovingRIGHT=true;

            }
            else{
                isPawnMovingLEFT=false;
                isPawnMovingRIGHT=false;

            }
        }
        if(pieces[rowStart][columnStart].FindPiece().charAt(0)=='B'){
            if(isPawnMovingUP==false && isPawnMovingUP2==false && (rowStart+1)==rowEnd && (columnStart-1)==columnEnd && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]!=null && piecesDevour(pieces, rowStart, columnStart , columnEnd, rowEnd)==true && columnStart!=columnEnd){
                isPawnMovingLEFT=true;

            }
            else if(isPawnMovingUP==false && isPawnMovingUP2==false &&  (rowStart+1)==rowEnd && (columnStart+1)==columnEnd && pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd]!=null && piecesDevour(pieces, rowStart, columnStart , columnEnd, rowEnd)==true && columnStart!=columnEnd){
                isPawnMovingRIGHT=true;

            }
            else{
                isPawnMovingLEFT=false;
                isPawnMovingRIGHT=false;
            }
        }
        return isPawnMovingUP || isPawnMovingRIGHT|| isPawnMovingDOWN || isPawnMovingLEFT || isPawnMovingUP2 || isPawnMovingDOWN2;
    }
    public boolean piecesDevour(ChessPiece[][]pieces,int rowStart,int columnStart ,int columnEnd,int rowEnd){
        firstLetter = pieces[rowStart][columnStart].FindPiece().charAt(0);
        if (pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd] != null) {
            secondLetterNotNull = true;
            secondLetter = pieces[rowEnd][columnEnd].FindPiece().charAt(0);
        } else {
            secondLetterNotNull = false;
        }
        if (secondLetter != firstLetter && secondLetterNotNull) {
            pieceDevour = true;
        } else {
            pieceDevour = false;
        }
        return pieceDevour;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you have a question?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: You designed chess as a text-based Java program? please share the code. I'll be surprised enough.

Comment: Wow, Chess game. Do you use JavaFX? Or text-based means CLI...

Comment: Chess is hard but also a good task for a language learner. But we can't really help you unless you show the relevant parts of your code. Also, I suggest you learn how to use a debugger as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow.   In order for us to help you, you must give us two things : 1) a clear statement of the problem (ie, what you want or expect to happen, and what is happening), and 2) a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .   For (1), I’m afraid what you have written doesn’t describe the problem - I have no idea what you mean by “ get the Pawns on either to move.”.   For (2) you have not provided any code.

Comment: I can share the answer but I am not sure if I can make an edit on this one because I see a character limit.

Answer (score 0):

isMoveValid will always return true.

```
    boolean pieceMove1 = false;
    boolean pieceMove2 = false;
    boolean pieceMove3 = false;
    boolean pieceMove4 = false;
    pieceMove1 = true;
    pieceMove2 = true;
    pieceMove3 = true;
    pieceMove4 = true;
    return pieceMove1  || pieceMove2 || pieceMove3 || pieceMove4;
```

pieceMove1 through 4 will all be true when the last statement is evaluated, and true OR true OR true OR true equals true. I'm not even sure what you are trying to accomplish here, so I cannot tell you how to fix it, but generally you should rethink how you structure your data types and which class actually *needs* which information.